# How should we [compose] this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm following all the Kotlin questions and I noticed that there was no tag for Jetpack Compose.

While Stack Overflow has four tags for variants of compose:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jetpack-compose
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose-desktop
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose-multiplatform
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains-compose

I figured that Code Review wouldn't need four tags.

While there are some minor differences between Jetpack Compose for Android and Jetbrains Compose Multiplatform, as a heavy Compose user myself, if feel that they are closely related and could use the same tag (at least for the time being)

For now I named the tag [kotlin-compose](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-compose) as Kotlin is the least common denominator, but is there another name? Should we separate Jetpack Compose for Android from Jetbrains Compose Multiplatform (which targets both Android, Desktop, iOS and also alpha support for Web) ?

*(Note: You might want to read up on [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) vs. [Jetbrains Compose Multiplatform](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-multiplatform/))*

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, are all Android Jetpack Compose & co related? Or are the four systems more like Docker Compose vs Jetpack Compose.

Comment: @Peilonrayz They are all related. The code you write for Compose Multiplatform is really similar to the one you write for Jetpack Compose Android. Compose Desktop is a subset of Compose Multiplatform, and Jetbrains Compose is the old name for Jetbrains Compose Multiplatform. But even if you write code for Compose Desktop, then you will still import lots of classes with packages starting with `androidx.compose`, e.g. `androidx.compose.ui.Modifier`. I also added links to the two main different ones, but if you can look at example code I think you will see that there's a lot of similarities...

Comment: @Peilonrayz You might also want to read the tag descriptions on Stack Overflow, I think that also shows how closely related they all are.

Answer (score 3):

I was [reminded about tag synonyms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63810472#63810472).

Looking at the options:

- android-jetpack-compose - not all questions are related to Android
- compose-desktop - is a small subset of compose-multiplatform
- compose-multiplatform - although this is the new name for Jetbrains Compose, not all code is written to be multiplatform, some might be specific for Android.
- jetbrains-compose (what is now known as Compose Multiplatform) and jetpack-compose (which is only for Android) are so similar, and all import the package `androidx.compose`

I think the best solution is to tag questions as [jetbrains-compose](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains-compose) as that is the most generic of them all.

And then if someone one day manages to convince me that there's a big enough difference for having two tags, then it can be revisited.